# Choosing between local and server data

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have some working code, but it seems a bit clunky.

I need to get data from a service. The service will hold the data in local storage if possible (to make it speedier), but if it's not been accessed before, it will need an http `GET` to a web server. The example contains only one `GET`, but there could be many in the future.

Service code

```
var module = angular.module('myapp.service', ["ngStorage"]);

module.service('jsonlistservice', function ($http, $q, $timeout, $localStorage) {

    var getStuff = function(){

      if ($localStorage.stuff != undefined && $localStorage.stuff != "") {

        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
          var x = {};
          x.data = $localStorage.stuff;
          resolve(x);
        });

        }else{
            return $http.get('data/sample.json').success(function(response){
              $localStorage.stuff = response;
            });
        }
    };

    return{
        getStuff: getStuff,
    };
});
```

From a controller this would be accessed like so:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'myapp.service'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'jsonlistservice', function($scope, myappservice) {

    var myDataPromise = myappservice.getStuff();
        myDataPromise.then(function(result){
            $scope.test = result.data[950].Id;
            console.log("returned");
        });


}]);
```

What is the correct pattern for this sort of thing please?

Comment: Actually, I tihnk this might be the wrong way to go about it. Maybe something like the observer pattern mentioned here is more appropriate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/how-to-watch-service-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with your existing code, the promise part can be simplified.

```
var getStuff = function(){
  return !!$localStorage.stuff ? $q.resolve({ data: $localStorage.stuff })
                               : $http.get('data/sample.json').then(function(response){
                                   $localStorage.stuff = response;
                                   return response;
                                 });
};
```

You appear to check against `undefined` and a blank string for stuff, both falsy values. We can simplify by coercing them to a boolean using `!!`. Another improvement is using `$q.resolve`, which returns an already resolved promise, resolved value optional. In the same way, `$http.get` also returns a promise. We can simply just return them instead of creating a new promise wrapper.

```
myappservice.getStuff().then(function(result){
  $scope.test = result.data[950].Id;
  console.log("returned");
});
```

We can also chain the `then` to `getStuff` since `getStuff` returns a promise. Much easier to follow chained stuff than breaking them apart (might be personal preference, but chaining makes code appear like sentences instead of commands).

As for a pattern, I think this one is fine since this is a one-off request (call and get) and the controller has been shielded from knowing where the data came from.

However, if you decide to go stream this data in, like say from a websocket, or make your service poll for changes, or react to localStorage events, then the suggested Observer Pattern might be your best bet. Make your service collect callbacks and fire them when something interesting happens.